# Updating URLs in many posts

Tags: urls

I copied my WP content to a new install on a different server, so now my uploaded PDF documents have the old URL. Is there a simple way to fix that in all my posts at once, perhaps with SQL or some plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the script found here:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Because WordPress [serializes](http://nl.php.net/serialize) some urls in option and meta tables a simple replace won't do.
A siple replace will break your data.
This script will preserve your data and replace it with a new url.
I use it al least twice a month.

Comment: Worked for me, thx!

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the [Velvet Blues](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin and it has worked great for me.  I couldn't say though how it may or may not handle serialized data.  The "easy" factor is pretty hard to beat though.

Answer (score -1):

Go back to the old install. After you exported the SQL database, open it up in any text editor and do a "search and replace", taking your old url and replacing it with your new url. So if I'm going from `http://localhost:8888/testsite` to `http://testsite.com`, I need to a search and replace:

- **Search:** `http://localhost:8888/testsite`
- **Replace:** `http://testsite.com`

Make sure you leave off the `/` at the end as you may miss a few URLs when you do your replacing.

Now just import this new database into the new install.

Comment: This is a bad way to do it. WordPress serialises some data. If you do this it will break that data.

Comment: Sure. Never had an issue doing it this way and I've done it for sites with 1000+ posts/comments etc. so thought I'd mention it.

Comment: This works for the case where you're modifying links in posts, but not if you're trying to modify data that might have been saved by a plugin. Better to use a search/replace plugin to do it.